# Compile multiple Latex files in parallel

Tags: pdftex, compiling, python

I have around 100000 Latex scripts, each of which generates a document upon compilation, and they share same packages being included. I tried compiling 10  scripts in a sequential fashion using Python script, by using **check_call** and **pdflatex texscript_name** method, but it took around 40 seconds to complete the compilation of 10 Latex scripts. 
If is using the same script to compile the rest of my scripts it will take around ~10 days, which sounds infeasible to me.

Is there any way to fasten the process of compilation?

Comment: It sounds like you should have a wrapper script that loads the preamble and concatenates the files (without preambles)  into sensible sized batches before splitting the resulting pdf.  This is still in series but with less to do per compilation. Is the page count fixed/easy to compute? Can you provide some examples of the generating .tex files?

Comment: This seems to be one of the rare cases where defining a new TeX format might be useful. All the included packages then don't need to be processed over and over again on every compilation run but are pre-loaded from a binary file directly when the compilation begins. Have a look at the [`mylatexformat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat) package for how to create new formats yourself.

Comment: The *best* solution to the problem is probably to do whatever you are trying to do without having 100,000 separate documents! But if that isn't an option, get a PC with multiple cores in the CPU, so you can run several compiles in parallel. If you use `gnu make` it will schedule another compile as soon as one finishes, so  you don't lose time if some documents take  longer to compile than others. ON a 6-core Intel I7 I can run more than about 10 LaTeX compiles in parallel before the CPU usage reaches 100% - that would cut the time from 10 days to 1 day, and the whole job will run "hands off."